# How to migrate existing schemas to known baseline using liquibase or flyway

Tags: mysql, database, liquibase, flyway

We want to introduce database schema versioning on an existing schema, because the current way of handling the schema versioning (manually) has lead to differences in the schema in the various databases in production.

For the sake of definition: when the word 'database' is used in this question, I mean the set of tables, views, procedures etc. that are available to 1 customer. Each customer has his own database. Several databases in 1 MySQL server instance. We have several MySQL servers running.

Context:

- multiple MySQL databases in production
- version of database is defined by the product that uses the database, i.e. multiple versions exists in production

Problem:

- databases of the same version differ slightly in schema definition
- unclear if schema migrations have been correctly applied

I've tried Flyway (commandline) and defined a baseline of a certain version and created migration scripts to migrate the database version to schema of the latest version. Obviously this works well when you start with a known baseline.
So we need to migrate all databases to a known baseline.

When I read the documentation and multiple articles about setting the baseline it all comes down to: 'figure out what the baseline should be and migrate the database manually to this baseline'.

However, since there are multiple databases in production (> 500) which differ slightly even when 'in the same version', it is not possible to manually change the databases to the desired baseline.

Is there a way with either Flyway or Liquibase to say something like 'migrate this schema to this baseline' which comes down to a set of 'if this column doesn't match the desired schema alter table modify column....' statements?

I'd settle for changes in tables only and recreate all views, triggers, procedures etc. anyway.

I read that Liquibase can do a 'rollback', but since MySQL doesn't support transactions on DDL, I wonder if this is implemented in Liquibase or only available for database servers that DO support transactions on DDL.
If anyone knows, please let me know. This might be an argument to move from Flyway to Liquibase.

Comment: Note that Flyway always wraps migrations in a DSL transaction. Once it is committed, there is no rollback possible, regardless of whether your database supports DSL transactions or not. All you can do is issue a compensating transaction.

Comment: Do your databases different in tables or procs or both? Do they have to differ or is it just too much of a task to get them in sync?

Comment: There are differences in the table schemas which shouldn't be there. There are too many tables and databases to check and migrate manually. We already have a mechanism in place to keep the procs, views and such in sync.